# Nessus doesn't find self-written plugins

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, detection, plugins

I'm trying to write a nessus plugin. So I took an existing plugin (10056), and only added the line 
display("hello world");
in the appropriate section and altered the script_id to a non-existing one. 
I chose that plugin because that is one that gets found on a test machine. This modified plugin is saved in the typical folder /opt/nessus/lib/nessus/plugins with all the other plugins as pesa.nasl.

A test-run with nasl -t  pesa.nasl prints the expected "hello world".

But when I run nessus again, after re-starting the daemon, the plugin doesn't get detected. Not when I look into the findings list, and also it's nowhere in the policies part that shows the plugins.

Any ideas what I need to do additionally, that nessus reads my self-written plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that nessus-update-plugins doesn't only fetch the newest updates from the nessus servers, but also tells the daemon about the new files that are placed in the plugin folder. 
So /opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-update-plugins does the job.